# How to access ids from different class inside the main class in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I created custom classes for list with check box, so in the `.kv` file the second class is inside the first class. In the second class I added an `id:` so I want to access that class through the `id:`.

And the First class is the `MDList` where the second class is the `MDCheckBox`.

```
class ListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    pass


class LeftCheckbox(ILeftBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass
```

The `.kv` file:

```
        ListItemWithCheckbox:
            text: "List One"

            LeftCheckbox:
                id: 'id_one'
                group: 'group'

        ListItemWithCheckbox:
            text: "List Two"

            LeftCheckbox:
                id: 'id_two'
                group: 'group'
```

So, now I want to access these ids `id_one` and `id_two` in a custom function inside the main Class check when these check boxes are active.

something like this:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def custom(self):
        id1 = LeftCheckbox.ids.id_one
        id2 = LeftCheckbox.ids.id_two
```

I'm new in kivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things, first do not add quotation marks around the id name in the kv file.

These should be

```
    ListItemWithCheckbox:
        text: "List One"

        LeftCheckbox:
            id: id_one
            group: 'group'

    ListItemWithCheckbox:
        text: "List Two"

        LeftCheckbox:
            id: id_two
            group: 'group'
```

Typically the way you access ID's is using the id's property of a widget. Now the app class doesn't have an id property, so you will have to pass `root` before calling ids, i.e.

```
class MainApp(App):
    def custom:
        self.root.ids['id_one']  # Accesses the widget with the id of id_one
        self.root.ids['id_two']
```

The ID of a widget is a dictionary with the keys as the ids you've defined and the values a WeakProxy to the widget.

For completion here is some sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string(
    """
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        id: button_one
        pos: 0, 0
        text: 'hello'
        on_release: app.custom()
            
"""
)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

    def custom(self):
        print(self.root.ids['button_one'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Pressing the button prints `<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x1098ea270>`

Comment: I got an error ```print(self.root.ids['id_one'])
 KeyError: 'id_one'```

Comment: my bad, my problem was I was adding quotation marks around the id name in the kv file. Now it worked.